# How to Disable URL Link Previews in iMessage iOS11 (or iOS10, Mac OSX Sierra)

Tags: ios, ios10, ios11, imessage

Unable to send links between my developers via iMessage, as the "preview" feature of iMessage in iOS11 & iOS10 is making it hard to see the exact URL structure, because it is instead inserting a link preview. Is there any way to disable this? Driving us crazy!!

Comment: Try overriding the `MSMessageTemplateLayout`.

Comment: Nop, same here, it's really annoying. I cannot find any settings to avoid that. @New16, I think he is talking about iMessage in general, not iMessage extensions ;)

Comment: I wish there were a way to disable this for all incoming messages. I consider it a security risk.

Comment: @duozmo can you elaborate on what part of this you consider a security risk given that the link redirection and preview rendering is happening on apple's servers (vs on the client)?  is it mainly the fact that someone could use it to determine if an arbitrary phone number is using imessage, about potential exploits, etc?

Comment: Ah, didn't realize it was happening on the server. @TaylorD.Edmiston Not saying you're wrong, but do you have a source?

Comment: @duozmo Hmm, I may be.  I can't find any public Apple docs that declare how they render previews aside from this one that discusses reachability wrt auth walls (not being able to pass the auth wall for previews).  Unfortunately it doesn't mention client or server-side.  My understanding was that they did something similar to what Gmail did to kill pixel trackers in emails by immediately loading the preview server-side and then caching it.  Now I'm curious if that's actually correct.  https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2444/_index.html

Comment: This article suggests that other messaging apps use server-side rendering for link previews, but that iMessage does not / cannot due to its end-to-end encryption. https://9to5mac.com/2020/10/26/researchers-demonstrate-how-link-previews-in-apps-can-expose-data-from-users/amp/

Comment: I wonder if link previews go through iCloud Private Relay when it's enabled.  Sounds like there are certainly some open questions here.  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212614

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Surround the URL with periods.

Example ".http://google.com."

iOS even removes the periods for you So it shows as "http://google.com" < no periods

Comment: Awesome trick! I love that, like you mentioned, iMessasge removes the periods and you get a clean url. Thanks!!!

Comment: Works the same with just one period after the URL. The points are visible on the preview of the message (messages listing) but then when opening the message, the points are trimmed.

Comment: This is the best solution. Thank you. Period in front and after solves the problem. What a simple and valuable hack. Graciassss!

Comment: Front period was retained on iMessage for Mac Mojave. Trailing period was removed

Comment: It seems like only the trailing dot is enough under iOS13

Comment: does anyone know if this "period hack" is a (documented) feature or a bug?

Answer (score 19):

Some of the other blogs I have read suggest that for the preview to work certain requirements must be met, if these are not met the preview will not be displayed (this should mean the full URL path is then visible):

1. The first requirement is the the link has to be either at the beginning of the text message, or at the end of the text message. If the hyperlink is placed in the middle of the text message, iOS 10 will not show a preview.
2. The second requirement for the new iPhone iOS 10 to render a hyperlink preview is that the hyperlink must start with http:// or https://.

Comment: Wow, you first tip worked... as long as you surround the URL with text, the preview is not enabled. For example, if I wanted to send my dev the full link I could text:  "test http://rushhourlocal.com/ test" and the preview would not work, even if the full URL is present.  THANK YOU SO MUCH!!

Comment: i suspect that (1) is only true for non-whitespace characters.  normal spaces definitely don't work, but i have not tested this more extensively as far as the more usual / invisible whitespace, etc type characters.

Answer (score 10):

With some experimenting it seems the rule is:

1. Repress preview if the URL appears in the middle of text
2. A dot can stand in for the text — and won’t show

These all hide the preview, and hide the dots:

- my text http://www.example.com my text
- my text http://www.example.com.
- .http://www.example.com my text
- .http://www.example.com.

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 12 and MacOS Mojave this can be done by just adding a dot (.) after the url (instead of both before and after mentioned in the accepted answer).

**Example**

`http://google.com.` becomes `http://google.com` in plain text

Answer (score -7):

Settings => Messages => MMS Messaging => OFF

Comment: Disabling iMessage does not answer the question of stopping previews within iMessage. This is just a snarky, unhelpful answer.

Answer (score -12):

Settings -> Notifications -> iMessage -> Show Previews. Turn that off.

Comment: This removes the message preview from the homescreen while the phone is locked, it does not turn off the message preview feature

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5030327?tstart=0